# C++ code that look perfectly fine causes error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I ran this code on Visual studio Professional 2013 and it worked, but it doesn't work on Visual Studio Express 2013.

```
#include "cli_tcp.h"


cli_tcp::cli_tcp()
// CLIENT TCP PROGRAM
// Revised and tidied up by
// J.W. Atwood
// 1999 June 30



char* getmessage(char *);



/* send and receive codes between client and server */
/* This is your basic WINSOCK shell */
#pragma comment( linker, "/defaultlib:ws2_32.lib" )
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>

#include <winsock.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

#include <string.h>

#include <windows.h>
```

Error   1   error C2144: syntax error : 'char' should be preceded by ';'
Error   2   error C2761: '{ctor}' : member function redeclaration not allowed
    3   IntelliSense: expected a '{'

I didn't post the entire code, because it was irrelevant. The only line that seems to be wrong is: char* getmessage(char *);

Comment: `cli_tcp::cli_tcp()`?!? Should this be `cli_tcp::cli_tcp() { /* the sample code */ }`? That code doesn't _look perfectly fine_ :-/ ...

Comment: I don't know I was given this sample code to run it on my machine.

Comment: Well how do you know it looks perfectly fine? `cli_tcp::cli_tcp()` is either an implicit constructor call - which is wrong in this place - or it should be `cli_tcp::cli_tcp(){/*code*/}`. The errors say all you need to know. Just read them and try understanding.

Comment: I ran the code as it was on Visual Studio Professional. Why wouldn't it work on Visual Studio Express. I didn't write the code.

Comment: @user3435009 _"I ran the code "_ I can't really believe this! The code you're showing won't run anywhere, because it simply doesn't compile. Be conscious about what you're doing. No matter if you have something _given from elsewhere_.

Answer (score 0):

You are simply not doing what you should when you state "cli_tcp::cli_tcp()".
The compiler is expecting you to provide the implementation for the constructor of the class, and you are not providing anything.

this

```
cli_tcp::cli_tcp()
```

should be

```
cli_tcp::cli_tcp() { /*code*/ }
```

or else it won't work anywhere.